# SwiftUI tool bar button does not navigate to another view

Tags: swiftui, toolbar

I am trying to navigate to another view by pressing on Toolbar button and it does not respond. I embedded the Button inside NavigationLink. How else can I do this?

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                NavigationLink {
                    DisplayContactView()
                } label: {
                    Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Contacts")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                EditButton()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            ToolbarItem {
               NavigationLink(destination: AddContactView()) {
                Button(action: { })  {
                   Label("Add Contact", systemImage: "plus")
                   .foregroundColor(.black)
                 }
               }     
        }
        Text("Select a Contact")
    }
}
```

Comment: Search for "SwiftUI programatic navigation"

Comment: I could not find the right answer for toolbar button

Comment: It being in the toolbar isn't relevant -- can you post your attempt at doing programatic navigation?

Comment: I posted that exactly above in my code. It programatically navigates to another view when I select the row, but does not work for the tool bar button. I enclosed the button in NavigationLink. Sorry, I am new to SwiftUI and I dont know any better than this.

Comment: What you have is not programatic navigation. Have a look at https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-programmatic-navigation-in-swiftui for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // A new state var on false by default
    @State var showAddView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                // ForEach + NavigationLink
            }
            .navigationTitle("Contacts")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Add", action: { showAddView = true })
                        // When the var is true the content is presented
                        // You can also use .toggle() instead of = true
                        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showAddView, content: { AddView() })
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's another example with a `.sheet` instead of a `.fullScreenCover` : https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-present-a-new-view-using-sheets

Comment: That worked and displayed the new view.  But I cannot slide the new view and get back to previous view.

Comment: I did this and it seems to work.
ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: AddContactView()) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                 }

Comment: I display the AddView and in the AddView, I save the data to coredata in onAdd method . How do I throw a alert and slide back to previous view, after save.
 ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
         
                    Button("Save", action: { onAdd(fullname: nameInput, ph: phoneInput) } )
                        .disabled(nameInput.isEmpty || phoneInput.isEmpty)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
func onAdd (fullname: String, ph: String)  -> Void {let contact = Contact(context: context) // update try? context.save() }

Comment: Everything you need to know is inside the link below the code I proposed. To close the new view after your logic is done you have to call the func `dismiss()`. Also, do not use a `NavigationLink` inside the toolbar and do not put your logic inside the button that call the new view.

Comment: method 1:
ToolbarItem { Button { showAddView.toggle() } label: {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus") .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showAddView) { AddContactView() } }
   method 2:
ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: AddContactView()) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus").foregroundColor(.black) }}
Both these methods work the same. Why are you saying don't use navigationLink